# Unable to obtain a class object of a generic type without using raw types

Tags: java, class, generics, collections, raw-types

Consider the following:

```
public interface Converter<I, O> {
    public Class<I> getInputType();
    public Class<O> getOutputType();
}
```

If I implement the interface and fill the type parameters with non-generic types, everything is still fine:

```
public class ConverterImpl implements Converter<UUID, String> {
    public Class<UUID> getInputType() {
        return UUID.class;
    }
    public Class<String> getOutputType() {
        return String.class;
    }
}
```

However, if I implement the interface and fill the type parameters with generic types, here is the problem:

```
public class ConverterImpl<T> implements Converter<Collection<T>, String> {
    public Class<Collection<T>> getInputType() {
        return Collection.class; //Compile time error
    }
    public Class<String> getOutputType() {
        return String.class;
    }
}
```

because `Collection.class` returns `Class<Collection>` instead of `Class<Collection<Something>>`. However, raw types are designed only for backwards compatibility and is not recommended to use. Is using raw types the only solution for this situation?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `Collection<T extends Something>`?

Comment: The question is really what is the purpose of the `getInputType()` and `getOutputType()` APIs. Is it meaningful to the caller to get the "class object" at runtime if it can't possibly represent the full type of `I` or `O` if they are non-reifiable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `Collection.class` to a `Class<Collection<T>>` .
Try with this:

```
public Class<Collection<T>> getInputType() {
    return (Class<Collection<T>>) (Class) Collection.class;
}
```